# Get uint from hex-string in C

Tags: c, string, hex, type-conversion

Let's say I have a `char*` called code, and it has `"0x41"` in it.

```
char *code = "0x41";
```

How can I convert that into an `unsigned int`? (To be exact, I need a `WORD`, but that's just an `unsigned int`).

Comment: I don't understand why this got a `-1`. Sure the guy is confused but its a legitimate coding question (compared to the plethora of other continuos questions that are "what framework should I pick"). It creates a hostile environment to new comers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
unsigned int h;
sscanf(code, "%x", &h);
```

**EDIT** taking account of the remark of ***ExP*** : `%x` could catch the value in the string `"0x41"`

Comment: Don't worry, be happy! The -1voter probably had nothing significant to say... Remember, numbers are just an indicator of how helpful you've been, and based on your numbers you've been fairly helpful. Anyway... Here, have a +1!

Answer (score 4):

I gather you mean that variable declared as `char *code = "0x41";` points to the string denoted by `"0x41"`.

There is no such thing as a `WORD` in C, but if you've got it typedef'd as an `unsigned int`, then you can convert this string of hexadecimal digits to an `unsigned int` like so:

```
char *code = "0x41";
unsigned int foo;
assert(sscanf(code, "%X", &foo) == 1);
```

You may note the use of `assert` in this code. I suggest replacing that assertion with logic to report an error when the return value isn't 1, as this would indicate that the string isn't in the correct format to be parsed as specified.

Comment: Actually, `0x` is redundant in `"Ox%X"`, since `%X` should catch it (it does for me).

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *code = "0x41";
    char *ck;
    long unsigned lu;

    lu=strtoul(code, &ck, 16);
    printf("%lu\n", lu);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use strtol function it convert string to unsigned  long integer for any base you want

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/